# Why JS object always sorts itself by key?

Tags: javascript, php

I get `msg_data` from MySQL query with `ORDER BY` msg_time clause.
I use then use foreach loop to create JS object of objects like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var active_swaps = {
    <?php if (is_array($msg_data) || $msg_data instanceof Traversable):?>
        <?php foreach($msg_data as $msg_item):?>
            <?php echo $msg_item['id'];?> : <?php echo json_encode($msg_item);?>,
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif;?>
    };
</script>
```

if I check `$msg_data` with `var_dump` I get:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=20)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'user1_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'user2_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'hasto' => string '2' (length=1)
      'requested' => string '2017-01-20 14:28:00' (length=19)
      'accepted' => null
      'swapped1' => null
      'swapped2' => null
      'rejected' => null
      'rejected_by' => null
      'swap_seen' => null
      'msg_id' => string '23' (length=2)
      'sender_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'msg' => string 'awdwadwd' (length=8)
      'msg_time' => string '2017-01-20 15:58:06' (length=19)
      'swap_id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'seen' => null
      'user1username' => string 'user1' (length=5)
      'user2username' => string 'user2' (length=5)
      'online' => string 'false' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=20)
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'user1_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'user2_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'hasto' => string '2' (length=1)
      'requested' => string '2017-01-20 15:57:51' (length=19)
      'accepted' => null
      'swapped1' => null
      'swapped2' => null
      'rejected' => null
      'rejected_by' => null
      'swap_seen' => null
      'msg_id' => string '22' (length=2)
      'sender_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'msg' => string 'awdawd' (length=6)
      'msg_time' => string '2017-01-20 15:58:00' (length=19)
      'swap_id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'seen' => null
      'user1username' => string 'user1' (length=5)
      'user2username' => string 'user2' (length=5)
      'online' => string 'false' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=20)
      'id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'user1_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'user2_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'hasto' => string '2' (length=1)
      'requested' => string '2017-01-20 15:11:58' (length=19)
      'accepted' => null
      'swapped1' => null
      'swapped2' => null
      'rejected' => null
      'rejected_by' => null
      'swap_seen' => null
      'msg_id' => string '20' (length=2)
      'sender_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'msg' => string 'awdadwdwa' (length=9)
      'msg_time' => string '2017-01-20 15:46:44' (length=19)
      'swap_id' => string '6' (length=1)
      'seen' => null
      'user1username' => string 'user1' (length=5)
      'user2username' => string 'user2' (length=5)
      'online' => string 'false' (length=5)
```

However in JS `console.log(active_swaps);` returns this:

```
Object {5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object}
```

No matter what I do it is always sorted by key(swap_id)! Would appreciate if someone could explain why is that happening?

Comment: Maybe it is not so good to use `numbers` for json object properties!? Test it with `echo "id{$msg_item['id']}";`.

Comment: The order of properties in a javascript object *are not guaranteed*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Thanks everybody for pointing out the real issue. In one of answer I wound this: `Current Browsers: order is preserved with the major exception of keys like "7" that parse as integers and are handled differently by Chrome/V8.`. Are there any more reasons to not use integers as keys? If I find another solution for order, can I use integers as keys?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you're creating an object with `$msg_item['id']` as key :

```
var active_swaps = {
<?php if (is_array($msg_data) || $msg_data instanceof Traversable):?>
    <?php foreach($msg_data as $msg_item):?>
        <?php echo $msg_item['id'];?> : <?php echo json_encode($msg_item);?>,
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
};
```

is interpreted in your loop as :

```
var active_swaps = {
    5 : 'JSON Object',
    6 : 'JSON Object',
    7 : 'JSON Object',
};
```

*(Nota : I replaced here the actual JSON string by `'JSON Object'` for readability)*

You should create an array instead of an object (which means numeric and 0-indexed keys *(Thanks to @CharlotteDunois for pointing that out)*), as such :

```
var active_swaps = [];
<?php if (is_array($msg_data) || $msg_data instanceof Traversable):?>
    <?php foreach($msg_data as $msg_item):?>
        active_swaps.push(<?php echo json_encode($msg_item);?>);
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Which would be equivalent to :

```
var active_swaps = [];
active_swaps.push('JSON Object');
active_swaps.push('JSON Object');
active_swaps.push('JSON Object');
```

Then `console.log(active_swaps)` should return the following :

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

**EDIT** : Keeping the output as an object

You could use the key of your `$msg_data` as your JS Object key :

```
var active_swaps = {
<?php if (is_array($msg_data) || $msg_data instanceof Traversable):?>
    <?php foreach($msg_data as $key=>$msg_item):?>
        <?php echo $key;?> : <?php echo json_encode($msg_item);?>,
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
};
```

The output of `console.log(active_swaps)` would now be `Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object}`, supposedly keeping the same order as your PHP array (ie 5, then 7, then 6)

Comment: That arrays don't have keys is actually false. They have keys, but they are numeric and 0-indexed.

Comment: further, this question is actually a duplicate.  Please vote to close (if you choose "duplicate", the already-selected-by-another-user duplicate is already listed for you, so you don't have to find it).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: While this works I need object not array. @ JustOnUnderMillions comment is correct.

Comment: Well, you could also use an object with numeric and 0-defined keys. Or with any other key that you'd like.What I was trying to demonstrate here is that the keys of your JS object are identical to `$msg_item['id']` because, in your loop, that's the value you're setting to the keys.

Comment: @KārlisJanisels I edited my answer with a snippet for creating an object, (supposedly) keeping the PHP array order, please check it out.

Comment: Sorry, meybe I have not explained myself correctly. I need those keys to be reference to swap_id. I want to use it like active_swaps[swap_id].requested